# yii2 routing для Search model

Tags: yii2, search, model

Есть модель поиска типа ApartmentSearch
Для поиска в неё передаются GET параметры в переменную $params.
Он выглядит следующим образом.

```
array(2) {
["page"]=>
int(1)
["ApartmentSearch"]=>
array(3) {
   ["subway"]=>
   string(0) "1"
   ["neighbourhood"]=>
   string(0) "2"
  }
}
```

Я хочу сделать url вида domain.com/subway/1
UrlManager пишу правило `['pattern' => 'subway/<subway:\d+>', 'route' => 'apartment/index', 'defaults' => ['page' => 1]]`
Но тогда параметр subway приходит не вложенный в массив ApartmentSearch.

```
array(2) {
 ["page"] => int(1)
 ["subway"] => int(1)
}
```

Как мне написать правило чтобы этот параметр положить внутрь ApartmentSearch, но при этом url бы остался таким же?
Тогда моя модель будет видеть этот параметр и мне не надо будет городить костыли.

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать для чего это? Обычно domain.com/subway/1 открывает страницу с описанием модели. Не хочется городить костыли, а это уже костыли :)

Comment: для того чтобы сделать посадочные страницы для определенных поисковых запросов. Типа выбрать все апартаменты по количеству комнат и т.п. Возможно это и костыль, если есть другой вариант я бы его использовал.

Comment: Что мешает загрузить этот параметр в форму? $form = new Search(); $form->load($get); $form->parametr = $parametr; Или перед load добавить параметр в массив $get.